# Orientation Changes distorted the View in Android device

Tags: android, user-interface, titanium, screen-orientation

My app is done in Titanium. I am struggling with a issue which is that when I= launch the App by keeping the device in landscape mode. Then while loading Splash screen it first goest in Landscape mode and when app finally launches Whole UI got distorted by that orientation change. I have added the below line of code in TiApp.xml

```
<application android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"/>
```

even though its rotating. I want to stop the orientation change of that splash screen while launching. Any idea?

Comment: Try changing to this `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`. And move both of them (screenOrientation & configChanges) to your Activity as `nick` suggested.

Comment: insted of screenOrientation in application, write it in the activity you want to be in portrait mode. And please let me know if any issue happens..

Comment: <activity url="app.js" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden> if doing like this it throwing me exception.Now Please tell me.

Comment: if put with <application> same issue happens. Now Please tell me what should i do

Comment: Even i tried below code also in app.js before opening the first Window but hard luck,didn't work.if (Titanium.Platform.name == 'android') {
  Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) {
   Ti.Android.currentActivity.setRequestedOrientation(Ti.Android.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  });
 }

Comment: hey, are you add custom androidManifest.xml file. plz tell me than i can help you... N also share this is tabbar application or Not :D

Comment: i tried but that was giving me error, once again i will try and let you know.Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

In each activity you have to write

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="landscape"  />
```

Hope it help!!

Comment: Hard Luck, Not Working.My first View is distorting only.Others are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add you custom androidManifest.xml [For custom xml](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Maintaining+a+Custom+AndroidManifest.xml)

and add this line in androidManifest.xml and run I think this is very useful for you.

```
<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Cheers